# Randomize vertex location without intersecting faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

Good day everyone, I can't seem to be able to randomize the vertex locations of a mesh without having faces intersect, is it possible in Blender 2.9 or newer to randomize vertex location without faces intersecting? Is there a way to move the vertices in a mesh so they stop before trespassing or crossing a face?

As an example I've attached 4 images, the first 2 show the mesh before and after applying the randomize operation in edit mode, and the last two images show an example face intersection which I want to avoid. I'm looking for a solution like the "Clamp Overlap" option in the bevel operation, which stops beveling the mesh when faces would intersect. Thank you

[image: Mesh before randomization]

[image: Mesh after randomization]

[image: Example1 of face intersection]

[image: Example2 of face intersection]

Comment: Did you try having the normal setting (in the lower-left menu - Image 2) at 1.0 instead of zero ?

Comment: Thanks for the attention, yes I tried that and the faces still intersect, I can post the screenshot if you want @AhmadBilal

Comment: Either make the value small enough that at 2x verts still cannot overlap, or consider using a script to set or fix.

Comment: Maybe a Python script could help?

Comment: A script would be good, but then does that mean that Blender doesn't have this feature? Is there any add-on to achieve this?